Questions about part of the proof of the general Halting Problem based on the string procedure
When reading mcs.pdf, it says in chapter 8.2:
$P_s$ definition

When a string $s \in \text{ASCII}^*$ is actually the ASCII description of some string
procedure, we’ll refer to that string procedure as $P_s$ . You can think of $P_s$ as the
result of compiling s into something executable.

Proof

Focusing just on string procedures, the general Halting Problem is to decide,
given strings s and t , whether or not the procedure $P_s$ recognizes t . Following the
usual diagonal approach, we define the language No-halt:
$$
\text{No-halt} ::= \{s\;\vert\; P_s \text{ applied to s does not halting}\} = \{s \notin lang(P_s)\}.\qquad(8.3)
$$
...
Theorem 8.2.2. No-halt is not recognizable. (Proof of Theorem 8.2.2 is skipped here)
So that does it: the reasoning above applied to whatever favorite programming
language you picked. It is logically impossible for a Java program to be a recognizer
for non-halting Java programs

In the above, "recognize" means same as "halt".

When the computation of a procedure applied to a string halts, the procedure will
be said to recognize the string.

Although I can understand one proof using the diagonal argument differently which tries to construct one counterexample (Here is the assumed program solving the Halting Problem) different from all existing instances (Here are all computable programs with 2 arguments)，but I have the following questions about the proof used in mcs.pdf
Q:

Here No-halt means the set of strings that can't recognized by some programs, i.e. ensuring $P_s$ can't halt for $s$ but maybe halt for all other inputs. But how does No-halt mean same as the non-halting programs?
We only show some strings / programs can't be recognized (i.e. we know some programs won't halt) which seems to imply we can decide whether they halt. Then how does the above Theorem 8.2.2 imply the Halting Problem is impossible?


Please don't use "Edit".  Especially don't use "Wrong stuff.  Edited: Here is a correction: Right stuff".  Instead, revise the question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  Delete everything that is wrong.  Introduce material in a logical order.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755 for more detail.

Please ask only one question per post.  If you have multiple questions, you can ask them separately.

I have seen someone using "Edited" in SO or others, so I thought it may be ok. By your  reference link, maybe I should avoid "Edited" from now.

@D.W. Since these 2 questions are really closely related, I ask them in one QA. If I ask them in 2 QAs, then the preparation material needs duplication or reference to the other detailed one. Do you mean the latter?

You have already received an answer to this one, so any change at this point would cause more problems than it is worth.  It's a judgement call what to do when you have multiple related questions.  In the future, I suggest either (a) asking just one of the questions, and waiting a few days for an answer, and see if you still have the second question after seeing the answer to the first, or (b) asking both questions separately at the same time, and provide full context in both (not just a link).

Thanks. IMHO asking one question at first and try understanding the 2nd based on the answer of the 1st may be preferable.


For every one-input program $s$, you can create a program that requires no input and just simulates $P_s(s)$. So, if you had a recognizer for non-halting programs with no arguments (assuming that's what you mean), you could use it to recognize $\textrm{No-halt}$.

We cannot decide whether programs halt. We can recognize it in the sense used in the book, because that just means we have to halt on the halting programs. This is easily achieved by just executing the program.
To decide something, you must create a machine that always halts, and classifies its input as either 'yes' or 'no'. But the naive recognizer for halting programs above only halts for inputs that halt, so it is not a decider. You can do better, but you cannot perform perfectly because...
If you did have a decider, then you could create a recognizer for $\textrm{No-halt}$ by deciding halting, and going into a loop exactly when the answer is 'yes.' But their proof shows there is no recognizer for $\textrm{No-halt}$, so there must not be a decider for the halting problem.
In general, a language being decidable is equivalent to both the language and its complement being recognizable.



Thanks. You solve the 2 questions by assuming the more general conclusion to prove and getting one contradiction while I originally tried to prove the conclusion directly. 1. As you says, since $s$ and $P_s(s)$ have the bijection direction, recognizing one of them means recognizing the other, e.g. transforming $s$ to $P_s$ and then do as the recognizer of $P_s$. Then iterate for No-halt, we can recognize it. 2. Based on 1, decider on whether $P_s(s)$ halts means same as the decider on whether $s$ is in No-halt.

After viewing the posted answer, the above questions should have the following correction:

${P_s(s);\vert;s\in\text{No-halt}}$ instead of No-halt means same as the non-halting programs.



"We only shows some strings / programs can't be recognized", i.e. no programs will halt with one valid output like True/False when having the string $s$ / program $P_s(s)$ to recognize as the input. This doesn't mean we know $P_s(s)$ won't halt, but means the program with input $P_s(s)$ won't halt, i.e. won't recognize $P_s(s)$. In a sum, the above "i.e. we know some programs won't halt" is wrong. Could you help checking whether my correction is right based on your answer? Thanks in advance.

